# Destroy input box

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a text tool using a input box with this [CanvasInput](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/108/CanvasInput-HTML5-Canvas-Text-Input) library.

I can render the text to the canvas using the *enter key*, my missing part is to destroy the input box so that I can reuse the text tool. The way I'm trying to destroy the box with `input.destroy();` , it stops working but it still shows in the canvas and I can't use that tool again.

How can I properly destroy the input box?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pedrovil/pen/wJPJmO)

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

**JS**

```
var inputBox=0;
var input;

function text(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.target.value);

  ctx.font = '32px serif';
  ctx.fillText(e.target.value, mouseX, mouseY);
  input.destroy();
}

function drawText(ctx,x,y,size) {
    if (inputBox==0){
        inputBox=1;
           input = new CanvasInput({
              x: mouseX,
              y: mouseY,
              canvas: document.getElementById('sketch'),
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: 'Arial',
              fontColor: '#212121',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              width: 200,
              padding: 8,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              borderRadius: 3,
              boxShadow: '1px 1px 0px #fff',
              innerShadow: '0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
              placeHolder: 'Enter message here...',
              onsubmit : text
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a bug, file an issue to the author, it should be easy for him to explain to you or fix that than others do.

Comment: you mean, to the library author?

Comment: yes, file an issue on github